# ie Filter not supported

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

ie is not being nice to me. A part of my jquery code has a `.filter()` and ie is throwing a tantrum saying that it is in correct syntax.

Is there a way around this?

The line is

```
const lines = nar.split("\n").filter(line => line);
```

Comment: That isn't jQuery.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter   IE support is IE 9+ and Edge (see the bottom).

Comment: Um, if you are having issues with filter not being supported, I think you are going to have issues with the fat arrow syntax....

Comment: It's not clear what you want your `filter` to do. At the moment [you're just returning the same data that you get from the `split`](https://jsfiddle.net/7hgLqjk2/). It's redundant.

Comment: @Andy It's not redundant, it filters out all the falsey elements (in this case, all the empty strings). The `function` argument to `.filter()` is required.

Comment: Huh. So it does. Learned something new today at least. cheers @Barmar.

Comment: @Andy You might be thinking of PHP `array_filter`, where the function is optional and it defaults to the identity function.

Comment: This is why [tag:internet-explorer] is [the most disliked tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/10/31/disliked-programming-languages/)

Comment: @ctwheels Can we ban internet explorer from existing?

Comment: @zazvorniki I wish, I truly do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE 9 + does support filter, but it does not support arrow functions or `const`, you should replace them with:

```
var lines = nar.split("\n").filter(function (line) { return line; });
```

You can also get around this by transpiling by using something like [babel](https://babeljs.io/)

However if you are targetting IE < 9 then you might also need to [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Polyfill) the function

```
if (!Array.prototype.filter)
  Array.prototype.filter = function(func, thisArg) {
    'use strict';
    if ( ! ((typeof func === 'Function' || typeof func === 'function') && this) )
        throw new TypeError();

    var len = this.length >>> 0,
        res = new Array(len), // preallocate array
        t = this, c = 0, i = -1;
    if (thisArg === undefined)
      while (++i !== len)
        // checks to see if the key was set
        if (i in this)
          if (func(t[i], i, t))
            res[c++] = t[i];
    else
      while (++i !== len)
        // checks to see if the key was set
        if (i in this)
          if (func.call(thisArg, t[i], i, t))
            res[c++] = t[i];

    res.length = c; // shrink down array to proper size
    return res;
  };
```